# HttpSessionListener doesn't work on my Spring MVC application

Tags: spring, session, listener, config

I have implemented HttpSessionListener in my Spring MVC application and it doesn't work. 
In my app, session is managed with Spring Jdbc Session and worked with Spring Security.
I read from some answers that Spring jdbc doesn't support HttpSessionEventPublisher.

In each case, firstly I tried to configure the listener in web.xml with the classic way.
Below the configuration:

```
<!-- BEGIN - IDG - session management -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<!-- END - IDG - session management -->

<!-- BEGIN - IDG - security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<!-- END - IDG - security -->

<listener>
    <listener-class>
         it.gov.ali.listener.CustomSessionListener
    </listener-class>
```

CustomSessionListener implement HttpSessionListener and its methods sessionDestroyed and sessionCreated.

Now when I make a logout with Spring Security, session is correctly invalidated and row session in my database is deleted but I don't hit my custom listener.

is there a particular way to configure a session listener with spring jdbc or I missed something?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring session jdbc, HttpSession is backed by the spring session.
So if you are using spring-session 2.2.1.RELEASE dependency then please look in getSession method in SessionRepositoryFilter class at line number 314 this might be useful and you can override this class to get you desired results.